# How use cv2.estimateAffine2D() using python with opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, affinetransform, image-stitching, ransac

i have 6 images, and I need apply the next algorithm, stitching image with affine transformation based Ransac:

1. find Matches features between 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5, 5:6
2. Select a reference image
3. Assemble the transitions between each image and the reference image plane (All images are on the reference plane)
4. The panorama is built on this plane

I was able to find the best matches between each pair of image (1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6) as requested in the first step.
But after that, I don't know how project each image on the same plane(for example: select the plane of the image 4, my reference image) using estimateAffine2D (). I have seen that this function calculates the matrix in case of an affine match, and uses ransac to save inliers only.
But i don't know how to use it, and after that how stitching images. Can someone helps me please, if there is an efficient clear algorithm to implement? or code example ?

thanks all for your help

Comment: extend the matrices to 3x3 by appending [0,0,1], then *matrix-multiply* them as needed (using infix `@` operator or `np.dot`, *not elementwise*). when putting 3x3 matrices into warpAffine, just slice the first two rows, dropping the third: `M[0:2]`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz after using estimateAffine2D() , i added as you proposed [0,0,1] to the 2x3  matrice, and after that i used the warpPerspective() function, is it possible or it's wrong ?

Comment: sure you can use warpPerspective but if the third row of the matrix is [0,0,1], its content is an affine transformation, so you could just as well use warpAffine (giving it the 2x3 part of the matrix). it's the same thing. if the matrix however *is* a true perspective transformation (last row isn't just [0,0,1]), then you can't use warpAffine. you could, but the result would be strange.